# Why content_arr['extended'] removes paragraph tags?

Tags: posts, functions, pages, content, the-content

I am running into a strange issue where `content_arr['extended']` or `content_arr['main']` is removing the paragraph tags in the output.

Any help, or insight into something i am over looking, trying to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

seems when i add the following using `wpautop` to the output it resolves the problem. i would love to know from someone smarter than myself why this fixes it. why when we just use `the_content` the p tags are included, but when we use `get_extended` do the p tags get removed?

```
$content_arr = get_extended ( $post->post_content );

            if( strpos( get_the_content(), '<span id="more-' ) == true ) {
                echo wpautop($content_arr['main']);
                echo '<div class="morecontent">'. wpautop($content_arr['extended']).'</div>';
            }
            else {
                the_content();
            }
```

Comment: Because calling `the_content()` will filter your content through [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter.

Answer (score 0):

`$post->post_content` does not have paragraph tags by default. Typically they are added when displayed using `the_content()` because `wpautop` is one of the filters applied when using this function. This also holds true for `do_shortcode` and a few other functions.

When displaying extended content on the page, you should to pass each part through the functions `wpautop` and `do_shortcode` etc, or apply the filter `the_content` instead.

```
<?php $parts = get_extended( $post->post_content ); ?>
<div class="post_content">
    <?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( $parts['main'] ) ); // Not entirely sure of the best order. ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $parts['extended'] ) ) : ?>
        <!-- Example Bootstrap toggle link. -->
        <a href="#read-more" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#read-more">
            <?php _e( 'Read More' ); ?>
        </a>
        <div id="read-more">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $parts['extended'] ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```